# Overide oncreate view using android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When I hold down alt and insert and go to `override` method and I select on create view from the list, the following does not show up

```
import android.support.annotation.Nullable
```

How do I get this information to show up and what does this mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile a specific library with your application to be able to use custom annotations like this one. In your app/build.gradle file make sure you've this:

```
dependencies {
    ....
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'
}
```

---

Edit:

[Here's](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) a tutorial how to install the Support Library. It's a little outdated though, so here's a screenshot of how the window looks in the newer AndroidStudio version:

[image: support lib example]

Comment: it has come up with an error saying can not find file ?

Comment: @user1727257 ahh yes you don't have the support library installed at all. I updated my answer to help you with that.

Comment: i will give this a try and let you know .

Comment: @simas- import android.support.v4.app.Fragment is not recognised by android studio am i missing a package that needs to be installed ?

Comment: @user1727257 that's from the Android Support Library.

Comment: @simas- android support library has been installed but android.support.v4.app.Fragment is still not recognised in android studio am i missing something ?

Comment: @user1727257 Add the dependency: `compile "com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0`.

Comment: @simas- i have added the dependency but now i get an error message saying android.app.fragment is already defined in a single-type import. what does this mean ?

Comment: @user1727257 Remove the default fragment import and refrain from asking multiple questions, especially in comments :)

Comment: Genius ! i have been stuck on this for a long time ^_^ .i won't ask multiple questions in comments